# Pop up with on click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I already made a photo gallery using a plugin which I want to show this gallery when user on_click my homepage button.

I am not sure how to achieve this please help me out here.

This is my button code:

```
<div class="ow-button-base ow-button-align-center">
    <a class="ow-button-hover" target="_blank" id="introduction" onclick="intro_on">
        <span>Click me to see gallery</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is my photo gallery code:

```
<div class="huge_it_slideshow_image_wrap_1" style="max-height: 1800px; overflow: visible;">
<div id="huge_it_loading_image_1" class="display" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#introduction span').click(function(){$('#huge_it_loading_image_1').show();});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery show() function:

$(".huge_it_slideshow_image_wrap_1").show();

but you need to set the display to none in your css file.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need jquery for this simple task.

Input a script tag in the bottom of your document with some javascript code in it.

```
<script>
    function intro_on() {
        document.getElementById("huge_it_loading_image_1").style.display = 'block'; 
    };
</script>
```

You also need to update the onclick in your html to "intro_on()" so it can be executed as a javascript function.